# Syntax error in expression (unexpected '}') in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a simple function that takes three Int values and returns the sum of the minimum and maximum integers out of these three.

My code:

```
summinmax3 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
summinmax3 x y z = 
  if (x > y && z < y) 
    then (x + z)
  else if (y > x && z < x) 
    then (y + x)
  else if (z > x && y < X) 
    then (y + z)
```

The code returns the error `syntax error in expression (unexpected '}'), possibly due to bad layout`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which compiler/interpreter do you use? That being said, every `then` needs an `else`. Also, Haskell is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing `else`. Every `if` needs both `then` and `else`, otherwise the return value wouldn't be determined, e.g. what should happen if `x` isn't even here?

```
add3IfEven x = if even x then x + 3
```

However, your compiler (Hugs) doesn't use your actual code, instead it transforms it into something else with curly braces:

```
{if … then … else … }
```

Since you're missing that last `else`, the `}` is unexpected. So make sure to add the correct `else` case. By the way, you can simply solve this exercise with `maximum [x + y, x + z, y + z]`.

Comment: I think the desired outcome is `minimum [x,y,z] + maximum [x,y,z]`.